# How to convert Drop downs onchange event to lists onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down list i did some functionality operation using onchange method .

bu some other page i want to use same functionality  in list view but i don't want to duplicate my script for list view any other possibilities.

```
<select id="filerProduct" name="filerProduct"  onchange="filerProductBySearch(this);">
<option value="aa" id="aa">AA</option>
<option value="bb" id="bb">BB</option>
</select>
```

Converting drop down view to list view below

**List View:**

```
<ul id="filerProduct" name="filerProduct">
<li value="aa" id="aa" onclick="filerProductBySearch(this);">AA</li>
<li value="bb" id="bb" onclick="filerProductBySearch(this);">BB</li>
</ul>
```

Script Drop-down onchange:

```
  function filerProductBySearch(event)
    {

        $('#filerProduct').val(event.value);
    }
```

i want to use same function to archive list onclick

Answer (score 0):

Pass specific value to the handler function. `event.target.tagName` could be used to get the `tag` on which event is invoked.

```js
function filerProductBySearch(value, event) {
  $('#output').text('Passed value is: ' + value + ' And element is: ' + event.target.tagName);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="filerProduct" name="filerProduct" onchange="filerProductBySearch(this.value,event);">
  <option value="aa" id="aa">AA</option>
  <option value="bb" id="bb">BB</option>
</select>

<ul id="filerProduct" name="filerProduct">
  <li value="aa" id="aa" onclick="filerProductBySearch(this.id,event);">AA</li>
  <li value="bb" id="bb" onclick="filerProductBySearch(this.id,event);">BB</li>
</ul>
<p id='output'></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the best practic here is

```
<select id="filerProductSelect" name="filerProduct" >
  <option value="aa" id="aa">AA</option>
  <option value="bb" id="bb">BB</option>
</select>

<ul id="filerProduct" name="filerProduct">
  <li data-value="aa" id="aa">AA</li>
  <li data-value="bb" id="bb">BB</li>
</ul>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('#filerProduct > li').click(
        {
          var value = $(this).attr('data-value');
          $('#filerProductSelect').val(value);
        })
    });
</script>
```